# E349: No identifier Under Cursor

Tags: vim

Every time I switch back to vim window, it shows the list, if current cursor on an empty line, it shows error: `E349: No identifier Under Cursor`.

[image]

Comment: when switch back to vim, the current file's content open in the below buffer window, and acted like command 'less', can use hjkl move the cursor.

Comment: I get this issue too. It's maddening. I commented out the entire .vimrc, but it still happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It caused by the [wincent/terminus](https://github.com/wincent/terminus) plugin.

**Fixed**

Append `let g:TerminusFocusReporting=0` to .vimrc

Comment: No, this solution doesn't work. You are right, it is absolutely outrageous and it only started happening today, but looking at the /var/log/apt/history* I can see that vim-common was upgraded ages ago (on 26th April 2018), so some other package is causing this.

Answer (score 6):

The only workaround for this problem that I've discovered so far was to run tmux and then run vim inside one of tmux's panes.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480138 ,
it is the FocusIn/FocusOut mode that can be disabled with:

```
echo -ne '\e[?1004l'
```

I encountered this problem when I would lose an ssh connection, so tmux on the remote server that enabled FocusIn/FocusOut mode would not be able to disable it. If I opened a vim on my local machine, vim would receive those events. If the FocusIn/FocusOut mode is not the default for your terminal, you can also disable it with:

```
reset
```

Comment: Met the similar problems on OSX and this solves it! Thanks! Not sure which program changes the terminal model.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

That list looks a lot like the output of `:ilist! Plugin` or `[I` with the cursor on `Plugin` or `]I` with the cursor on the first `Plugin`. See if you don't have that somewhere in your `vimrc` (that you should append to your question, by the way).

The error message is likely caused by `:help gd` or `:help gD`.

Comment: thanks for your answer and the jpg, but I think it's not caused by gd, no matter where, which file my cursor at, when re-focused, vim shows file content in this way:(, maybe I should comment the plugin one by one, and see if I'm lucky!

Answer (score 0):

Alt-tabbing into Terminal sends a ^] command to VIM. To ignore that command, put

```
nnoremap ^] <Nop>
```

in your .vimrc file

Comment: This solution doesn't work either, unfortunately. I.e. when I switch to the terminal tab where vim is running I get the list of strange items (like "map = ...") and when I move the focus away from that tab (or the whole terminal) then the list disappears. And it re-appears when I bring the focus back. I need to find out what is causing it asap because otherwise it is absolutely impossible to do any work...

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix by removing the line `set ttymouse=` from my `.vimrc`.

You may need to set `ttymouse` to an appropriate value, see `:h ttymouse`.

Answer (score 0):

I appeared in the 3.12 version of iterm2, and now it disappears after upgrading to 3.15